# Monitor for yum / rpm package conflicts

Tags: centos, rpm, yum, nagios, icinga2

We want to write a Icinga monitor to catch rpm package conflicts. e.g. from a "yum update":

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: git2u-core conflicts with git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64
```

Is there a way to run the "Dependency Resolution" independently of the "yum update" command? Or some other way to force yum to resolve the dependencies without installing or downloading anything in case of no error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with command `yum update --assumeno`.
This command will download just repodata, not packages itself.

Comment: Good idea, didn't know about that parameter! :D
Only downside is that I will have to parse the output for Errors because the RC will always be 1, even if the update would work.

Comment: @Tarwin just use `grep`, it will RC `0` if there is a match. In your case, having a match is actually a problem, so you can use the negate plugin to flip it around.